# Problem storing german chars in the MySQL database.....?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I have a table named "cust_details" which has a column "***categories***", where I have to store some categories like : **blockadenlösung, affirmation, beziehungsprobleme lösen**

But when I am trying to save this data into the database it is stored like :

**blockadenlÃ¼sung, affirmation, beziehungsprobleme lÃ¶sen**

That is when **umlauts** are coming in the string it is **not saved in its original form**. I tried some **charset** for storing this characters. But I am **still facing the problem**.....

What may be the possible reasons...?

Thanks In Advance.....

Comment: @Pekka : Like utf8_general_ci, utf8_unicode_ci etc.

Comment: Okay. Is the incoming data encoded UTF-8 as well? The database connection?

Comment: Good reading (not necessarily *right now* to solve this specific problem, but for a great insight into character sets): [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Pekka : Yes incoming data is encoded with UTF-8

Comment: You need UTF-8 encoding on the db table, field(s), db connection and the app (either via. a http header or meta tag). It's likely you are missing one of these.

Comment: I found the solution for my Zend Project by writing following code to application.ini file :


resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data you stored is encoded in UTF-8 (Ã¼ for an "ö" is typical for UTF-8), but is not displayed as UTF-8 but rather as ISO-8859-1 or the like.

Make sure that you use the same encoding everywhere:

- Deliver your websites with Content-Encoding "utf-8"
- Use mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); to set the encoding to utf-8
- Make sure that the encoding of the database is UTF-8 (use HeidiSQL etc. to check)

Answer (score 0):

Use this when you are inserting the characters:

```
N'characters here'
```

The N before the string declaration should enable you to enter it into the DB.

Comment: In which language? Not in PHP for sure. :)

Comment: I do apologise, I was thinking it was for MSSQL. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the field?

You could specify database/table/field level character-sets. The default `latin-1` works in most scenarios.

Otherwise, you would have to use plain text and store unicode strings like `&#<4-digit-unicode-value>;` into it. Then when you print it out, just dump the unicode into HTML and it will show up as such.

Here is a sample string in Pashto `&#1578;&#1585;&#1575;&#1601;&#1610;&#1705;&#1610; &#1662;&#1610;&#1690;&#1608; &#1705;&#1744; &#1583;&#1585;&#1744; &#1578;&#1606;&#1607; &#1605;&#1683;&#1607; &#1575;&#1608; &#1669;&#1608;&#1575;&#1585;&#1604;&#1587; &#1606;&#1608;&#1585; &#1660;&#1662;&#1610;&#1575;&#1606; &#1588;&#1608;&#1604;.` which we store directy into the table. The charset used is `latin_charset_ci`

Good Luck!